# Stitching video files to look as taken from single camera

Tags: video, camera

I am taking a movie using four cameras which are kept perpendicular to the arena("the surface where the event happens"). Is there a way to stitch the video files, so that it looks like the events are recorder using a single camera? The picture of the arena is attached.

[image: Picture of arena]

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated video stitching software is quite complex and is generally proprietary - it is used extensively in VR to create 360 degree videos from multiple cameras.

For your use case, it seems you may be able to do something simpler - if you pad one video with black or blank areas, and then superimpose the other videos in this blacked area you should be able to get the affect you want.

See this answer for a an example of the ffmpeg command for a side by side example, which you should be able to build on: https://superuser.com/a/537482